# What is the maximum distance for eavesdropping sound waves?

Tags: waves, acoustics

And what kind of device I need to use for eavesdropping?

Actually a microphone with a parabolic reflector or laser reflected listening devices available on the market but is there any other devices on the planet which should allow to eavesdrop at least 2-3kilometers?

Which tools and what kind of knowledge I need to know for manufacturing an ultra long distance/range eavesdropping device?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a question about physics

Comment: @JohnRennie I think it is about physics, but matches better engineering.

Comment: Nah, it's not about physics, in the sense encapsulated by our engineering close reason.

Comment: This is a motivated question and I see no reason to close it. Physical conditions sets the limit for such a device. Sound can however be detected from very much longer distance than the sound can travel with use of laser vibrometers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laser_Doppler_vibrometer